# There does not exist an order-preserving surjection from a poset to its down-set lattice?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

As in title. By "down-set lattice," I am specifically referring to the set of [lower sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set) of the poset in question, ordered by set inclusion.

I'm not even sure how to start. It feels true, because it looks like a function from a set to a subset of its power set, and I'd be very surprised if that were surjective. But I'm not sure where to take that hunch. I'd be very grateful for any help proving this claim.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start with some small posets.  Just draw a few concrete ones.  Then try to play with the thing on those.  If you can see what's going on with small examples, them you can probably figure out in general.

Comment: That said, I'm confused by this.  Think of the poset with one element, which seems to violate what you want.  What is it specifically that you want by the way?

Comment: I wanted to show the claim in the title, that there doesn't exist some such order-preserving surjection.

I don't understand why the one element poset is a counterexample. Aren't there two sets in its down-set lattice? The empty set, and the set containing the single element? Could be totally wrong, that's just what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.  Suppose $P$ is a poset, $L$ is its lattice of lower sets, and $f:P\to L$ is an order-preserving surjection.  Let me first sketch the argument intuitively; if you just want a briefer formal proof you can skip down to the bottom.  The idea is to inductively rule out all possible "sizes" of $P$.  First, can $P$ be empty?  No, it can't, since $L$ always has at least one element, namely the empty set.  So since $f$ is surjective, there is some $p_0\in P$ such that $f(p_0)=\emptyset$.

OK, now can $p_0$ be the only element of $P$?  No, because once we know $p_0\in P$, there is a second lower set in $L$, namely $\{q\in P:q\leq p_0\}$.  So let's pick $p_1\in P$ such that $f(p_1)=\{q\in P:q\leq p_0\}$.

OK, now can $p_0$ and $p_1$ be the only elements of $P$?  Well, consider the lower set $D_2=\{q\in P:q\leq p_0\text{ or }q\leq p_1\}$.  We can't have $f(p_0)=D_2$, since $D_2$ is not empty.  And we can't have $f(p_1)=D_2$, since $f(p_1)=\{q\in P:q\leq p_0\}$ and $p_1\in D_2$ so that would imply $p_1\leq p_0$.  But then since $f$ is order-preserving, we'd have $f(p_1)\subseteq f(p_0)$, which is impossible since $f(p_0)$ is empty and $f(p_1)$ is not.

Maybe we're done now: maybe $P$ has no elements besides $p_0$, $p_1$, and $p_2$.  Nope: consider the lower set $D_3=\{q\in P:q\leq p_0\text{ or }q\leq p_1\text{ or }q\leq p_2\}$.  You can prove that $D_3$ cannot be equal to $f(p_0)$, $f(p_1)$, or $f(p_2)$, so there must be some new element $p_3\in P$ such that $f(p_3)=D_3$.

And so on.  By repeating this procedure inductively, you can keep getting more and more distinct elements of $P$.  You can continue this transfinitely, to define distinct elements $p_\alpha$ for all ordinals $\alpha$.  This is impossible, since $P$ is a set.

---

OK, now here's the argument written more formally.  We will construct a sequence of elements $p_\alpha\in P$ for each ordinal $\alpha$ by transfinite recursion.  Having defined $p_\beta$ for all $\beta<\alpha$, let $D_\alpha=\{q\in P:q\leq p_\beta\text{ for some }\beta<\alpha\}$ (the lower set generated by the $p_\beta$).  Since $f$ is surjective, there exists some $p\in P$ such that $f(p)=D_\alpha$.  Define $p_\alpha$ to be such a $p$.

I claim that $p_\alpha\not\in D_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.  We can prove this by induction: suppose $p_\beta\not\in D_\beta$ for all $\beta<\alpha$ but $p_\alpha\in D_\alpha$.  Then $p_\alpha\leq p_\beta$ for some $\beta<\alpha$.  Since $f$ is order-preserving, this means $f(p_\alpha)\subseteq f(p_\beta)$.  By construction, $f(p_\alpha)=D_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$, so $D_\alpha\subseteq D_\beta$.  But $p_\beta\in D_\alpha$, so this gives $p_\beta\in D_\beta$, which contradicts the induction hypothesis.

Thus $p_\alpha\not\in D_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.  But $p_\beta\in D_\alpha$ for all $\beta<\alpha$ and so $\beta<\alpha$ implies $p_\beta\neq p_\alpha$.  Thus $\alpha\mapsto p_\alpha$ is injective.  This is a contradiction, since $P$ is a set and this map is defined for all ordinals.

(Note that this argument uses the axiom of choice to pick a $p_\alpha$ such that $f(p_\alpha)=D_\alpha$ in each step.  However, you can avoid using the axiom of choice by making all the choices at once.  That is, instead of picking just one new element $p_\alpha$, let $P_\alpha$ be the set of all $p$ such that $f(p)=D_\alpha$.  You then correspondingly need to define $D_\alpha=\{q:q\leq p\text{ for some }\beta<\alpha\text{ and some }p\in P_\beta\}$.)

Comment: Could you walk me through the third paragraph, starting with "And we can't have $f(p_{1})=D_{2}$...?" I don't see why that's true. I mean I believe you of course, I just don't understand it.

Comment: Which step in particular don't you follow?  I don't know what to say that isn't just repeating exactly what I wrote...

Comment: Sorry about that. I think that I understand that paragraph now. $\{q \in P \mid q \leq p_{0}\} = \{q \in P \mid q \leq p_{0} \text{ or } q \leq p_{1}\}$ implies that $p_{1} \leq p_{0}$.

Comment: Yes, that's right, since $p_1$ is an element of the right-hand side.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on, "You can continue this transfinitely?" To be clear, I understand what that means, I see why you're using it here, and I see how it works. It just feels odd. I've seen a lot of proofs that say, "You can continue this process infinitely" -- do they mean transfinitely? Is it just not worth making that distinction? Is there even a distinction? Sorry for the vagueness, I'm just trying to prompt any sort of discussion on that particular phenomenon. Specifying that a process can be continued "transfinitely," when I usually just see people saying, "infinitely."

Comment: By "transfinitely" I mean you can continue it in an inductive argument indexed by the ordinals (though in more general contexts "transfinitely" might just mean you can continue it for all ordinals up to some particular ordinal that will be determined later).  "You can continue this process infinitely" usually instead just means that you can continue it over all the natural numbers.

Comment: Sorry to revive this but I've confused myself again, unfortunately. I'm wondering why the argument you used for the existence of $p_{0}$ and $p_{1}$ (i.e. simply invoking the surjectivity of $f$) doesn't work for the existence of $p_{2}$, and so forced you to appeal to the order-preserving nature of $f$. Can't you just say, "There's a third lower set, so there must be a third element?"

Comment: Well, you know there exists $p_2$ such that $f(p_2)=D_2$, but that doesn't prove that $p_2$ is distinct from $p_0$ or $p_1$.  For that you need to check that $D_2$ is distinct from $f(p_0)$ and $f(p_1)$, which is exactly what I did.  (Technically, we needed to do this when defining $p_1$ as well, but I omitted it since it's obvious that $p_1\neq p_0$ since $f(p_1)$ is nonempty.)

Comment: And we need to show that $p_{2}$ is distinct from $p_{0}$ and $p_{1}$ because if it is not, then $f$ is not a function? Sorry, I find this very difficult so I like to be clear.

Comment: No, we want the $p_\alpha$ to all be distinct in order to eventually reach a contradiction.  The goal is to eventually conclude that $\alpha\mapsto p_\alpha$ is injective, which would imply $X$ is a proper class since this map is defined for all ordinals.

Comment: Why is it necessary to invoke order preservation when showing that $p_{2}$ is distinct? Can't you just say that it's clear that $D_{1} = \{ p_{0} \}$ and $D_{2} = \{ p_{0}, p_{1} \}$, so if $\phi(p_{1}) = D_{1}$ then $\phi(p_{1}) \neq D_{2}$?

Comment: Why is it clear that $D_1=\{p_0\}$?  How do you know $p_1\not\in D_1$?

Answer (score 5):

My purpose in posting this answer is to present a slightly streamlined version of the proof in [Eric Wofsey's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063103/there-does-not-exist-an-order-preserving-surjection-from-a-poset-to-its-down-set/2063128#2063128) and a slightly cleaner formulation of the result, and to put it in its historical context by giving references.

Note that, if the ordering of $P$ is trivial (no two elements are comparable), then we are saying that there is no surjection from the set $P$ to its power set $\mathcal P(P).$ In other words, this result is a generalization of [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem), although the proof is quite different from the familiar diagonal proof of that theorem. This generalized Cantor theorem was originally proved by [Gleason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_M._Gleason) and [Dilworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_P._Dilworth), and further generalized by Davies, Hayes, and Rousseau:

> A. M. Gleason and R. P. Dilworth, A generalized Cantor theorem, *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* 13 (1962), 704–705.
>   
> [Roy O. Davies, Allan Hayes and George Rousseau, Complete lattices and the generalized Cantor theorem, *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* 27 (1971), 253–258](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-027-02/S0002-9939-1971-0268091-0/S0002-9939-1971-0268091-0.pdf).

**Terminology.** A binary relation $\le$ is a [*quasi-ordering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) (or "preordering") if it is reflexive and transitive. A mapping $f$ between quasi-ordered sets is [*isotone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) (or "order-preserving") if $x\le y\implies f(x)\le f(y).$ A subset $D$ of a quasi-ordered set $Q$ is an [*lower set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set) (or "down-set") if, for all $x,y\in Q,\ x\le y\in D \implies x\in D.$

The question asks for a proof of (essentially) the following:

**Theorem.** If $Q$ is a quasi-ordered set and $f:Q\to\mathcal P(Q)$ an isotone mapping, then the range of $f$ can't contain all the lower sets of $Q.$

Note that the result can be restated in a way that doesn't refer explicitly to the ordering of $Q$:

**Theorem.** Given a set $Q$ and a mapping $f:Q\to\mathcal P(Q),$ we can find a set $D\in\mathcal P(Q)\setminus\operatorname{range}(f)$ such that for all $x,y\in Q$ we have: $f(x)\subseteq f(y),\ y\in D\implies x\in D.$

**Proof.** For each ordinal $\alpha$ define
$$D_\alpha=\{x\in Q:f(x)\subseteq\bigcup_{\xi\lt\alpha}D_\xi\}.$$
Clearly, each $D_\alpha$ satisfies the condition: $f(x)\subseteq f(y),\ y\in D_\alpha\implies x\in D_\alpha.$ All we have to do now is find some $D_\alpha$ which is not in the range of $f.$ Clearly, $\beta\lt\alpha\implies D_\beta\subseteq D_\alpha,$ so we always have $\bigcup_{\xi\lt\alpha}D_\xi\subseteq D_\alpha.$ If the proper inclusion $\bigcup_{\xi\lt\alpha}D_\xi\subsetneqq D_\alpha$ held for every $\alpha,$ then $\alpha\mapsto D_\alpha$ would be an injection from the class of all ordinals into $\mathcal P(Q),$ contradicting [Hartogs' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number). Thus, there is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that
$$D_\alpha\subseteq\bigcup_{\xi\lt\alpha}D_\xi.$$Considering the least such $\alpha,$ I claim that $D_\alpha$ is not in the range of $f.$

Assume for a contradiction that $D_\alpha=f(x)$ for some $x\in Q.$ Then $f(x)\subseteq\bigcup_{\xi\lt\alpha}D_\xi,$ so $x\in D_\alpha,$ so $x\in D_\beta$ for some $\beta\lt\alpha,$ and $f(x)\subseteq\bigcup_{\xi\lt\beta}D_\xi.$ But now we have
$$D_\beta\subseteq D_\alpha=f(x)\subseteq\bigcup_{\xi\lt\beta}D_\xi,$$
so $D_\beta\subseteq\bigcup_{\xi\lt\beta}D_\gamma$ and $\beta\lt\alpha,$ contradicting the minimality of $\alpha.$