# Possible similarities between a poset and its poset of endomorphisms

Tags: order-theory

The category variant of this question is posted separately [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3302519/660).

For any poset $X$, write $E(X)$ for the poset of endomorphisms of $X$ (with $f\le g$ for $f,g\in E(X)$ if and only if $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in X$), and consider the following properties a poset $X$ may or may not have:

(P1) $X$ is a singleton,

(P2) $E(X)$ is isomorphic to $X$,

(P3) there is an injective morphism $E(X)\to X$,

(P4) there is a surjective morphism $X\to E(X)$.

Clearly (P1) implies (P2), and (P2) implies (P3) and (P4):
$$
\begin{matrix}
&&1\\ 
&&\downarrow\\ 
&&2\\ 
&\swarrow&&\searrow\\ 
3&&&&4.
\end{matrix}
$$

Denote by (Qij) the question "Does (Pi) imply (Pj)?".

student9909 asked Question (Q21) [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/211489/461). (student9909 accepted an answer which doesn't answer the question. I find this very confusing. As far as I know, the question is still open.) Let us ask also:

> **Question (Q31)** Does (P3) imply (P1)?
>
> **Question (Q41)** Does (P4) imply (P1)?
>
> **Question (Q32)** Does (P3) imply (P2)?
>
> **Question (Q42)** Does (P4) imply (P2)?
>
> **Question (Q34)** Does (P3) imply (P4)?
>
> **Question (Q43)** Does (P4) imply (P3)?

Comment: @bof - It seems to me that Theorem 3 in http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-027-02/S0002-9939-1971-0268091-0/S0002-9939-1971-0268091-0.pdf (one of the links you gave) answers all the questions in this post, as well as the MO question. What am I missing?

Comment: No reason to think you are missing anything. Although I cited that paper, that doesn't mean I read it closely. Probably I only read bits and pieces that I needed, and by now have completey forgotten the arguments, which explains why I was having a hard time trying to aswer your question. I'm glad that I was able (somehow) to provide a useful reference (without understanding it myself), and I'm glad you can now answer all your questions!

Comment: Ah, I see. The answer to your questions was not in the Gleason–Dilworth paper but in the subsequent Davies–Hayes–Rousseau paper, which I never read. The only reason I linked to it in my answer was because that's what I found while searching unsuccessfully for a freely available copy of Gleason–Dilworth. Is that what they call serendipity? :-) Thanks for the kind references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact the four properties are equivalent. This follows immediately from Theorem 3 in

> [Roy O. Davies, Allan Hayes and George Rousseau, Complete lattices and the generalized Cantor theorem, *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* 27 (1971), 253–258](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-027-02/S0002-9939-1971-0268091-0/S0002-9939-1971-0268091-0.pdf).

This reference was pointed out to me by user [bof](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/111012/bof) in a (now deleted) comment. More precisely bof gave a link to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2064374/660) of them.